# Generate 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9 with `rep()` and `seq()`

Tags: r

I'm having a problem in creating the vector

```
1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

with `rep()` and `seq()`. Could anyone be able to give me a hint?

Comment: `kronecker(1:5, 0:4, "+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
rep(1:5, times = 5) + rep(0:4, each = 5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

or simpler (as R will recycle `1:5` automatically):

```
rep(0:4, each = 5) + 1:5
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

> Is there a way to do that with the command `seq`?

`1:5` is just `seq(1,5)`, while `0:4` is `seq(0,4)`.

---

**matrix representation**

For those who feel interested, we can also use `outer`:

```
as.numeric(outer(1:5, 0:4, "+"))
```

The initial call to `outer` generates this matrix:

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    2    3    4    5    6
#[3,]    3    4    5    6    7
#[4,]    4    5    6    7    8
#[5,]    5    6    7    8    9
```

then we use `as.numeric` to flatten it.

---

**A better solution**

Function `sequence` can now generate such sequence (it couldn't back in 2016):

```
sequence(rep(5, each = 5), 1:5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```